# I need to check if the observation is from specific countries and return a 1 or 0 in a new column

Tags: r

I have a column titled Country_Region which has observations of countries. I need to check whether the observations have entries `"USA", "UK", "Netherlands", "Germany", "Singapore"` and return a 1 otherwise return a 0 but in a new column titled Top5Countries.

I tried using ifelse but still did not get anywhere

```
cleaneddata<- if_else(cleaneddata$countryRegion == "Singapore"|"USA"|"UK"|"Estonia"|"Switzerland"|"Russia"|"Cayman Island"|"Germany"|"Netherlands"|"Malta",1,0)
```

This was the error i got

> Error in cleaneddata$countryRegion == "Singapore" | "USA" :
> operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

Comment: Can you provide `dput(cleaneddata)`?

Comment: use `%in%` - when you use `|` you must specify the variable every time (ie, `cleaneddata$countryRegion == "Singapore" | cleaneddata$countryRegion == "USA" ...`)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ifelse` like this:

```
library(dplyr)
cleaneddata <- cleaneddata |>
  mutate(Top5Countries = ifelse(countryRegion %in% 
                                  c("Singapore", "USA", "UK", "Estonia", "Switzerland",
                                    "Russia", "Cayman Island", 
                                    "Germany", "Netherlands", "Malta"), 1, 0))
```